# Time out when i want use file_get_contents()

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, file-get-contents, host

I want read content of a file from another website but can not read it.
I have access to both host.
I want use `file_get_contents()` function. What do I need to change in the file directory on file or folders? or in my PHP file?
[enter link description here](http://services.khazrait.ir/feeds/te.php)

`<?php`
`$direct="http://nic.subz.ir/api/index.php";`
`echo $direct;`
`echo  file_get_contents($direct);`
`?>`

Comment: please provide the code and sample links that you are accessing. Are you not able to get data using file_get_contents(); ?

Comment: Yes. i can not access to data  [code]$direct="http://nic.subz.ir/api/index.php";
echo $direct;
echo  file_get_contents($direct); [/code] http://services.khazrait.ir/feeds/te.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write here your example and error what you get.
If something about permission, so you have to send user agent in your request

Comment: I edited my question. i set chmod for files 644 and 777 , and for foder(directory) 755 and 777. and disabled modsecurity and too, htaccess by "allow all"